# What is the fastest way to read a list of jpeg images and convert it into TFRecords in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, tfrecord

I have a list of images and labels in a txt file, in this format:

file1.jpg 1

file2.jpg 0

file3.jpg 1

file4.jpg 1

where the labels are binary.

How could I convert the image data to a TFRecord file without assigning my images to a subdirectory of labels (which is used in the inception model data preparation), and through simply reading jpg images? I have seen the TFRecords tutorials from tensorflow but it seems that the images are already all constructed in a tensor form.

I have tried a solution from:
[How do I convert a directory of jpeg images to TFRecords file in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849617/how-do-i-convert-a-directory-of-jpeg-images-to-tfrecords-file-in-tensorflow)

But it didn't seem to work.

Comment: To be honest, I would just rearrange the files into the right directory layout and then use the inception preparation tool from here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/data/build_image_data.py . Can you elaborate why that won't work for you? You could alternatively adapt the importer code to understand your file layout. Can you say more about what went wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating TfRecords from a list of strings and feeding a Graph in tensorflow after decoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054656/creating-tfrecords-from-a-list-of-strings-and-feeding-a-graph-in-tensorflow-afte)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the code in the following link to solve your problem. I did exactly what you are asking for. (Converting a set of png, or jpeg, images to TfRecords (binary images). And I provided the way to read out the tfrecords. In addition, In my case, I have a a set of features which are stored in a string, and I stored them into the tfrecords.

[Creating TfRecords from a list of strings and feeding a Graph in tensorflow after decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054656/creating-tfrecords-from-a-list-of-strings-and-feeding-a-graph-in-tensorflow-afte/44099995#44099995)

Hope this code will help you.

Comment: If this is a duplicate of the old q/a then you should probably just have called it out a duplicate in a comment.