# How to read Ogg or MP3 audio files in a TensorFlow graph?

Tags: tensorflow, audio, ffmpeg

I've seen image decoders like `tf.image.decode_png` in TensorFlow, but how about reading audio files (WAV, Ogg, MP3, etc.)? Is it possible without `TFRecord`?

E.g. something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849617/how-do-i-convert-a-directory-of-jpeg-images-to-tfrecords-file-in-tensorflow):

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(['my-audio.ogg'])
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
my_audio = tf.audio.decode_ogg(value)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer from @sygi is unfortunately not supported in TensorFlow 2.x. An alternative solution would be to use some external library (e.g. [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown) or [librosa](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.load.html)) to implement the mp3 decoding step, and integrate it in the pipeline through the use of `tf.py_function`. So you can do something along the lines of:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('path/to/mp3s/*')

def decode_mp3(mp3_path):
    mp3_path = mp3_path.numpy().decode("utf-8")
    mp3_audio = AudioSegment.from_file(mp3_path, format="mp3")
    return mp3_audio.get_array_of_samples()

dataset = dataset.map(lambda path:
    tf.py_function(func=decode_mp3, inp=[path], Tout=tf.float32))

for features in dataset.take(3):
    data = features.numpy()
    plt.plot(data)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there are special decoders, in the package [tensorflow.contrib.ffmpeg](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/contrib.ffmpeg.html#ffmpeg-contrib). To use it, you need to install [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) first.

Example:

```
audio_binary = tf.read_file('song.mp3')
waveform = tf.contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio(audio_binary, file_format='mp3', samples_per_second=44100, channel_count=2)
```

Comment: tf.contrib ffmpeg is not available in windows somewhy, I have ffmpeg installed via conda and it simply does not work.. [tf github issue posted on here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8271)

Comment: That's great! In TensorFlow 1.10.0 you need to pass the `channel_count` parameter, otherwise it will throw the following error: `ValueError: Tried to convert 'channel_count' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.`

Answer (score 3):

Such a function has recently been added to [`tensorflow_io`](https://github.com/tensorflow/io) ([here](https://github.com/tensorflow/io/pull/857)).
You can use it like this:

```
content = tf.io.read_file(path)
audio = tfio.experimental.audio.decode_ogg(content)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the latest versions of tensorflow, All audio related utilities have been moved/added to tensorflow_io ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/io/api_docs/python/tfio/audio)). To install run `pip install tensorflow.io`

```
import tensorflow_io as tfio
import tensorflow as tf

fp = 'path/to/mp3'
audio  = tfio.audio.decode_mp3(tf.io.read_file(fp))
```