# Read mnist images into Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was looking at [this Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers).

In the tutorial the images are magically read like this:

```
mnist = learn.datasets.load_dataset("mnist")
train_data = mnist.train.images
```

My images are placed in two directories:

```
../input/test/
../input/train/
```

They all have a `*.jpg` ending.

So how can read them into my program?

I don't think I can use `learn.datasets.load_dataset` because this seems to take in a specialized dataset structure, while I only have folders with images.

Comment: Take a look at: https://gist.github.com/eerwitt/518b0c9564e500b4b50f

Answer (score 6):

mnist.train.images is essentially a numpy array of shape [55000, 784]. Where, 55000 is the number of images and 784 is the number of pixels in each image (each image is 28x28)

You need to create a similar numpy array from your data in case you want to run this exact code. So, you'll need to iterate over all your images, [read image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762948/how-to-convert-an-rgb-image-to-numpy-array) as a numpy array, flatten it and create a matrix of size [num_examples, image_size]

The following code snippet should do it:

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
def load_data(img_dir):
    return np.array([cv2.imread(os.path.join(img_dir, img)).flatten() for img in os.listdir(img_dir) if img.endswith(".jpg")])
```

A more comprehensive code to enable debugging:

```
import os
list_of_imgs = []
img_dir = "../input/train/"
for img in os.listdir("."):
    img = os.path.join(img_dir, img)
    if not img.endswith(".jpg"):
        continue
    a = cv2.imread(img)
    if a is None:
        print "Unable to read image", img
        continue
    list_of_imgs.append(a.flatten())
train_data = np.array(list_of_imgs)
```

Note:
If your images are not 28x28x1 (B/W images), you will need to change the neural network architecture (defined in cnn_model_fn). The architecture in the tutorial is a toy architecture which only works for simple images like MNIST. Alexnet may be a good place to start for RGB images.

Comment: That returns `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'flatten'`. For some reason it can't see the images even though I'm sure that I specified the correct folder.

Comment: Does the folder contain images that are not jpegs? You can try the more comprehensive code above to help debug for which images cv2 is returning None

Comment: Also try the updated one-liner code. My earlier code didn't work if not executed from the same directory as the images.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the answers given in [How do I convert a directory of jpeg images to TFRecords file in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849617/how-do-i-convert-a-directory-of-jpeg-images-to-tfrecords-file-in-tensorflow). Easiest way is to use the utility provided by tensor flow :[build_image_data.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/inception/inception/data/build_image_data.py), which does exactly the thing you want to do.

Comment: link is broken :(